# sqlite android FATAL EXCEPTION

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to store information from a webservice into a sqlite database. However when I try to store the data I receive a FATAL EXCEPTION: MAIN error and a null pointer exception. Here is my code. Any help would be very helpful. thx in advance.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

SQLiteDB sqlite_obj;

Button get, store;
List<String> list1, list2;

InputStream is = null;

String ip = "http://XXXXX.com/select.php?jszam=0000";
String line = null;
String result = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sqlite_obj = new SQLiteDB(MainActivity.this);

    get = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    store = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    get.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            webservice();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Success : Webservice Call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }           
    });

    store.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            sqlite();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Stored in SQLite DB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private void sqlite() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    sqlite_obj.open();

    sqlite_obj.deleteAll();

    for(int i=0; i<list1.size(); i++) {

        sqlite_obj.insert(list1.get(i).toString(), list2.get(i).toString());
    }

    sqlite_obj.close();
}

private void webservice() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(ip);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Webservice 1", e.toString());
    }
    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();         
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Webservice 2", e.toString());
    }
    try {

        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject jo = null;

        list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0; i<ja.length(); i++) {

            jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
            list1.add(jo.getString("id"));
            list2.add(jo.getString("uname"));
        }           
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Webservice 3", e.toString());
    }
}
```

}

**SQliteDB**

```
public class SQLiteDB {

public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SQLiteDB";

private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "sample";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
        "create table sample (id text primary key, name text not null);";

private final Context context;
private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public SQLiteDB(Context ctx) {

    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sample");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

//---open SQLite DB---
public SQLiteDB open() throws SQLException {

    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

//---close SQLite DB---
public void close() {

    DBHelper.close();
}

//---insert data into SQLite DB---
public long insert(String id, String name) {

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_ID, id);
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);

    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

//---Delete All Data from table in SQLite DB---
public void deleteAll() {

    db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
}
```

}

**Logcat**

```
07-16 15:05:52.811: D/memalloc(31042): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x547b0000 size:122880 offset:0 fd:79
07-16 15:05:52.811: D/memalloc(31042): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x507ad000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:81
07-16 15:05:54.731: D/memalloc(31042): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x547b0000 size:122880
07-16 15:05:54.731: D/memalloc(31042): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x507ad000 size:4096
07-16 15:05:57.241: W/dalvikvm(31042): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception ( group=0x41815540)
07-16 15:05:57.251: E/AndroidRuntime(31042): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 15:05:57.251: E/AndroidRuntime(31042): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 15:05:57.251: E/AndroidRuntime(31042):    at balaji.sqlite_webservice.MainActivity.sqlite(    MainActivity.java:81)
07-16 15:05:57.251: E/AndroidRuntime(31042):    at balaji.sqlite_webservice.MainActivity.access$1(  MainActivity.java:74)
07-16 15:05:57.251: E/AndroidRuntime(31042):    at balaji.sqlite_webservice.MainActivity$2.onClick( MainActivity.java:68)
07-16 15:05:57.251: E/AndroidRuntime(31042):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4102)
07-16 15:05:57.251: E/AndroidRuntime(31042):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17085)
07-16 15:05:57.251: E/AndroidRuntime(31042):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-16 15:05:57.251: E/AndroidRuntime(31042):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-16 15:05:57.251: E/AndroidRuntime(31042):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
07-16 15:05:57.251: E/AndroidRuntime(31042):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.  java:5520)
07-16 15:05:57.251: E/AndroidRuntime(31042):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 15:05:57.251: E/AndroidRuntime(31042):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-16 15:05:57.251: E/AndroidRuntime(31042):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller   .run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
07-16 15:05:57.251: E/AndroidRuntime(31042):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.  java:796)
07-16 15:05:57.251: E/AndroidRuntime(31042):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your stacktrace.

Comment: edited my post, check there

Comment: It seems that `list1` is null.

Comment: on emulator it works fine but on a normal phone it doesnt

Comment: Did you call the `get` Button before the `store` button?

Comment: yes I call the get Button before the Store button